# How to use the same complex type for multiple function imports?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a model(Complex type generated by entity framework) as below

```
public partial class Company
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress01 { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress02 { get; set; }
}
```

}

And I have added 2 function imports for stored procedures. One I am using to display a list of companies where I only return **CompanyID** and **CustomerName**
[image: Function Import 1]
[image: Function Import 2]

and a second stored procedure which returns the details of a specific company and "uses" all the fields in the model

In entity framework is there a way to use the same Complex type for multiple function imports even with unused fields? If this is not correct then what is the best practice in this situation?

When I try to run my GetCompanies it's complaining about unused fields.